# Why is Java looking for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, build-dependencies

I've used the search function and tried to solve this issue with the solutions raised but with no results.. I'm building a Minecraft plugin and in order move on I need to use MongoDB. I've implemented the dependencies with Maven and implemented "Maven shade plugin" to include libraries on runtime but with no results. I'm totally stuck now because I've the feeling I tried everything. Eclipse recognized it is a Maven project since the blue "m" is present.

On runtime Java cant find the class(es) it needs.

Console log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients
    at rico.polkadot.Main.onEnable(Main.java:182) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) ~[spigot.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
```

What I've tried:

- Adding dependencies with Maven
- Adding JAR to MANIFEST
- Adding JAR to build path in Eclipse

My POM.xml file:

[POM.xml](https://textuploader.com/tsjh0)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself.

Solution:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: libs/mongo-java-driver-3.7.1.jar libs/bson-3.7.1.jar libs/mongodb-driver-sync-3.7.1.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)

Needed to include ALL needed drivers/dependencies to MANIFEST file.